# Extend checkout order summary section in Magento 2

Tags: shipping-methods, magento-2.1.3, checkout-page, order-summary

I am trying to add custom text in beside **shipping method** section in **Order Summary** from Magento 2. But my data is not affecting.

[image]

For this, I have added custom text in **root\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\summary\shipping.html** file. But it's not effecting.

```
<span class="title">Custom Text</span>
```

Could you please suggest me which file I need to extend to add custom text?

Comment: Did you deploy static content?

Comment: @SureshChikani Yes, so many times. But it's not affecting.

Comment: Which command used for it?

Comment: @SureshChikani `php bin/magento setup:upgrade, php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy and php bin/magento cache:flush`.

Comment: Open it to privet window.

Comment: @SureshChikani Where? it is. Plz suggest me or send link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74230/discussion-between-magento-two-and-suresh-chikani).

Comment: @magentotwo have you given rights to pub/static/frontend and  var directories?

Comment: I added answer. Please check and accept if really solve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File path should be below

`vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/shipping.‌​html` file

Add your custom `<span class="title">Custom Text</span>`  text like below example

```
<!-- ko if: isExcludingDisplayed() -->
    <tr class="totals shipping excl">
        <th class="mark" scope="row">
            <span class="title">Custom Text</span>
            <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: title"></span>
            <span class="value" data-bind="text: getShippingMethodTitle()"></span>
        </th>
        <td class="amount">
            <!-- ko if: isCalculated() -->
            <span class="price"
                  data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': title}"></span>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: isCalculated() -->
            <span class="not-calculated"
                  data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': title}"></span>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </td>
    </tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to answer your question, please answer these questions yourself:

1. Do you have any virtual products in this quote?
2. Do you check if the `shipping.html` able to generate as your expectation (try to put some text in the beginning or at the end of file, then do inspection)

So, let take a look into

> vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\summary\shipping.html

```
<!-- ko if: quoteIsVirtual == 0 -->
    <tr class="totals shipping excl">
        <th class="mark" scope="row">
            <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: title"></span>
            <span class="value" data-bind="text: getShippingMethodTitle()"></span>
        </th>
        <td class="amount">
            <!-- ko if: isCalculated() -->
            <span class="price"
                  data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': title}"></span>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: isCalculated() -->
            <span class="not-calculated"
                  data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': title}"></span>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </td>
    </tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

As you can see above, obviously if the quote is virtual, it cannot show the shipping section.

My recommend is create a new jsComponent in order summary, then added it below the shipping section.

Something like

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <!--Cart Side bar on checkout index -->
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="mycustomstuff" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Stackoverflow_Toan/js/view/checkout/sumarry/mycustomstuff</item>
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">30</item>
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Custom Stuff</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                                <!--End-->
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now, it's time to add some JS

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/summary/mycustomstuff.js

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
    ],
    function (Component, quote, priceUtils, totals) {
        "use strict";
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed: window.checkoutConfig.isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed || false,
                template: 'Stackoverflow_Toan/checkout/summary/mycustomstuff'
            },
            totals: quote.getTotals(),
            isTaxDisplayedInGrandTotal: window.checkoutConfig.includeTaxInGrandTotal || false,
            isDisplayed: function() {
                return this.isFullMode();
            },
            getValue: function() {
                return 'oh-hello';
            }
        });
    }
);
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/mycustomstuff.js

```
define(
    [
        'Stackoverflow_Toan/js/view/checkout/summary/mycustomstuff'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({

            /**
             * @override
             */
            isDisplayed: function () {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Your knockout templates...

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/mycustomstuff.html

```
<tr class="totals customstuff excl">
    <th class="mark" scope="row">
        <span class="label" data-bind="text: title"></span>
    </th>
    <td class="hello">
        <span class="oh-hello" data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': title}"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/mycustomstuff.html

```
<tr class="totals customstuff excl">
    <th class="mark" colspan="1" scope="row" data-bind="text: title"></th>
    <td class="hello">
        <span class="oh-hello" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

*NOTE: This is just a draft version, use at your own risk. Hope it helps :)*